# Regex not matching numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

```
new RegExp('^\\d+[.]?([0,2,5,7]?[0,5])?$').test(236.70)
```

Why doesn't this code work for 123.20 and 123.70?  Whereas it successfully tests for the following inputs:

> 123.00, 123.05, 123.25, 123.50, 123.55, 123.75

Comment: Try to pass strings instead of numbers :)

Comment: You shouldn't put commas in a character class unless you intend to match commas. A regex literal should also be preferred. `/^\d+\.?([0257]?[05]?)$/`

Comment: Thanks @4castle, this helped

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the value `236.70` and most probably JavaScript is stripping the last `0` since `236.70 == 236.7`. Then, it does not match the last part of the regex, where you match the `[0,5]` ending.

Instead, cast it to string to force the trailing `0` to remain there.

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui

Answer (score 3):

There are some syntax errors with your regex.  In the part where you match the decimal, you have the `?` outside of the parentheses when it (probably) should be inside and you have `,`s in your character class even though you are not trying to match them.

Character classes (`[]`) require you to list the *individual* characters you want to match.  You can also get a *range* of characters using the `-` (eg. `[0-9]`).

```
new RegExp('^\\d+[.]?([0257]?[05]?)$').test(236.70)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: new RegExp('^([5-9]|[1-9][0-9])([.])?([0257]?[05])?$').test(00.50)
VM37068:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

why am i getting this error ???

Comment: @vikkyDevil: `00.50` isn't a valid number.  Try `0.50`, `0.5` or even just `.5`.